# NoMethodError when trying to print an associated table's data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, erb

I'm having trouble with my index.html.erb file.

By the way, **@events = Event.all**

```
15 <% @events.each do |event| %>
16   <tr>
17     <td><%= event.name %></td>
18     <td><%= event.maker_id %></td>
19     <td><%= event.maker.name %></td>
20     <td><%= event.category_id %></td>
21     <td><%= event.category.kind%></td>       #error
22     <td><%= event.location_id %></td>
23     <td><%= event.location.area %></td>
24     <td><%= event.description %></td>
25   </tr>
26 <% end %>
```

My *Event* table is associated with (has the foreign_keys of) my *Maker*, *Category*, and *Location* tables.

If **event.maker.name** works and prints the name of the associated Maker, how come the same logic/syntax doesn't happen with **event.category.kind** and **event.location.area**?

Instead, I receive:

> NoMethodError in Events#index
>
> Showing /Users/-/app/views/events/index.html.erb where **line #21** raised:
>
> undefined method `category' for # Event:0x007fb4c5b0f960

...where line #21 is ***event.category.kind***

My schema.rb is:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "kind"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "category_id"
  t.text     "description"
  t.string   "maker_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "location_id"
end

create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "area"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "makers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "password"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "password_digest"
end
```

Basically I want to output data from the associated tables, not the foreign_key id numbers themselves. Like this:

```
1 <% @events.each do |event| %>
2   <tr>
3     <td><%= event.name %></td>
4     <td><%= event.maker.name %></td>
5     <td><%= event.category.kind %></td>     #this would be an ERROR
6     <td><%= event.location.area %></td>     #this would be an ERROR
7     <td><%= event.description %></td>
8   </tr>
9 <% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have those association defined within the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event.rb

```
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :category
```

In view, you should call it as

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= event.name %></td>
     <td><%= event.maker_id %></td>
     <td><%= event.try(:maker).try(:name) %></td>
     <td><%= event.category_id %></td>
     <td><%= event.try(:category).try(:kind) %></td>       #error
     <td><%= event.location_id %></td>
     <td><%= event.try(:location).try(:area) %></td>
     <td><%= event.description %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: thanks. is the event.try(:category).try(:kind) syntax needed? because event.category.kind works well

Comment: If event object will have category_id then category association will be called and if category object is found then only it will try to call category's kind..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your models. `maker.rb` probably has the line `has_one :event`, and `event.rb` has something like `belongs_to :maker` but `category.rb` has no such reciprocal relationship with `event.rb`.

Edit event.rb to include:

```
belongs_to :category
```

Edit category.rb to include:

```
has_one :event
```

In order to easily reference one object from another, you have to specify the relationship between them (in both directions).